# I faced an error when trying to create device in cloud debugging on Huawei developer console

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

### On the loading page, I stuck with an error that says "Sign-in has expired".

#### Although I tried to log in again but still shows the same behaviour on the cloud debugging page.

Comment: Hi@Haris Bhatti，It is recommended that you check your network to see if it is connected to a VPN or proxy. If you could provide an error screenshot, it would be better. :)

Comment: @shirley thank you. Yes after disconnected the VPN, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've connected VPN service and after disconnecting it everything works fine.
Thank you @shirley for highlighting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to URL to login as developer if you have an account already:  [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console#/serviceCards/)
   [image]
2. Then select cloud debugging. See the below screenshot.
   [image]
3. And then you can select the device that suits your purpose.
   [image]

Comment: thank you for your help. But the issue was VPN service.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this article to create device in cloud debugging
[Efficient integration of HMS open capabilities by using HUAWEI Cloud Debugging solution](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201272130144230071?fid=0101187876626530001)

For official documentation you can check this link [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction)